# Confusion in representation of complex numbers .

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

[image]

To begin, in the above image, $z$ has been taken to to be $x+iy$, allowing a multiplication by $i$ to result in: $iz=-y+ix$. In the diagram, they have actually shown the 2nd quadrant than the 4th quadrant. If the point given by $z$ was in the 4th quadrant, then wouldn't the angle be $-90^{\circ}$?

Finally, when we have $x+iy$, then it means that the y axis is the imaginary axis. Only, here we see the x axis as said imaginary axis. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $i$ gives us the vertical position.

$x+iy$ corresponds to the coordinate $(x,y)$. When $x, y $ are both positive, it is a point in the first quadrant.

$iz=ix-y = -y+ ix$ corresponds to the point $(-y, x)$. If $x, y$ are both positive, the first coordinate $-y$ is negative and the second coordinate $x$ is positive and hence we get a point in the second quadrant.

In general $iz$ rotate $z$ by $90^\circ$ anticlockwise.

Comment: But it written it is in 4th quadrant sir.

Comment: I believe it is a typo.

Comment: They have also written that it is anti-clockwise.I do think you are right sir but this book has 2typos then anti-clockwise and 4th quadrant.They look to be confident when writing these 2 major points.

Comment: anticlockwise is correct. Just that the $4$-th quadrant I believe it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have two axes: the axis in the "$1$" direction and the axis in the "$\mathrm{i}$" direction.  Any point of the plane $(a,b)$ can be written as having coordinate $a$ in the $1$ direction and coordinate $b$ in the $\mathrm{i}$ direction:
$$  1 \cdot a + \mathrm{i} \cdot b  \text{.}  $$
Of course, no one ever writes down the "$1\cdot {}$", so we actually write and see
$$  a + \mathrm{i} b  \text{.}  $$

There is a potential ambiguity in the uses of $x$ and $y$.  $x$ is being used as both the label for the real axis and for the first coordinate of the point $A$.  $y$ is being used as the label for the imaginary axis and for the second coordinate of the point $A$.  It would have been better to not use the axis labels as coordinates of the point $A$, but it was done.  You may be better served (mentally) replacing the label on the horizontal axis with "Re" and the label on the vertical axis with "Im".

So you start with point $A$ having coordinates $(x,y)$, corresponding to the complex number $x + \mathrm{i} y$.  Notice that $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, so $A$ is in the first quadrant.  Then you multiply by $\mathrm{i}$, obtaining $\mathrm{i} x - y$.  That is, you have
$$  1 \cdot (-y) + \mathrm{i} \cdot x  \text{.}  $$
This is the point with coordinates $(-y,x)$ which has negative first coordinate (left half-plane) and positive second coordinate (upper half-plane), so is in quadrant II, as labelled by the point $B$.

Comment: Oh right.I think it is a typo in book only then.

Comment: To write it in 4th quadrant

Comment: @user282657 : Agreed.  It happens.  I made two typos in the first version of this answer...

Answer (score 0):

The notation is misleading. It would be easier to understand, if they used following notation:

- Coordinates of the point A: z1 = x1 + iy1
- Coordinates of the point B: z2 = iz1 = x2 + iy2 = -y1 + ix2

Answer (score 0):

You’re letting the letters $x$ and $y$ confuse you. Let’s start with a complex number $u+iv$ instead, where $u$ and $v$ are positive real numbers. This complex number has real part $u$ and imaginary part $v$. (Remember, the imaginary part is the coefficient of $i$.) It is plotted at the point $\langle u,v\rangle$ in the first quadrant, because we normally plot the real part on the $x$-axis and the imaginary part on the $y$-axis.

When you multiply the number by $i$, you get $ui-v$, or $-v+ui$. Now the real part, i.e., the part without the factor of $i$, is $-v$, and the imaginary part is $u$, so we plot the complex number at the point $\langle -v,u\rangle$, which is in the second quadrant.

It’s fine to use the terms *$x$-coordinate* and *$y$-coordinate* instead of *real coordinate* and *imaginary coordinate*, or *abscissa* and *ordinate*, but only if you remember that the $x$ and $y$ in these terms have nothing to do with the symbols used to denote the actual coordinate numbers. This is true even when you’re just dealing with points in the plane: the $x$-coordinate of the point $\langle y,x\rangle$ is $y$, not $x$.

Comment: Ok.It means that even x axis at some point van be imaginary or real axis and same for y.zit just depends on the number

Comment: @user282657: The horizontal axis is always the real axis, and the vertical axis is always the imaginary axis. The letter $x$, however, can be used for the real part, as in $x+iy$, in which case it’s an $x$-coordinate, **or** for the imaginary part, as in $y+ix$, in which case it’s a $y$-coordinate. $x+iy$ is plotted at the point $\langle x,y\rangle$; $y+ix$ is plotted at the point $\langle y,x\rangle$.